# Understanding SSL/TLS certificates structure

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

Could someone explain, how are all certificates built?

There are many files that are generated while getting a certificate (.csr .key .cert .pem).

What each file contain?
From what I already got .key file is a file with private key.
From that .key is generated .csr, which can be send to CA.

However webhosting providers each ask for different set of files (or name it randomly?). How to distinguish which file is which?

For example .pem and .cert files, each start with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` which is confusing (at last for me).

Any kind soul would care to explain how it all works?

Comment: `.cert`is not a standard. It is often used as synonym for `.pem`. `.pem`indicates that you have all data in bas64 encoding encapsulated by `---- BEGIN / END ...` sections. For the other file formats see Wikipedia.

Answer (score 2):

PEM is an encoding that is also used as extension. All files that start with `-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----` are PEM encoded. Even the .key. That said, a .pem file could be a key, a certificate, a chain certificate, etc. You should name it well to know what it is.

All .crt and .cert extensions mean the file is a certificate. The Certificate Authority chooses which extension they will send the file.

The .csr is also PEM encoded, but it is a *Certicate Signing Request*. It is created when you generate your .key file. With it you can ask for a CA to issue a certificate for you.

**---Edit---**

Based on your comment, you have received three files from letsencrypt: `cert.pem`, `chain.pem` and `fullchain.pem`. You also might have a `privkey.pem`.

To configure your certificate you can bother using just the `privkey.pem` and `fullchain.pem` which is just a concatenation of `cert.pem` and `fullchain.pem`. You need to setup those files in your web server, each web server is different and you might look for their specific instructions.

Comment: Could you add more info? What set of files do I need to install certificate to server. And what is PEM file exactly? I got files from let's encrypt ( by using https://gethttpsforfree.com/ ) and got file with .pem extension. Which i dont know what to do with it.